# Using GSAP with ScrollMagic

Tags: frontend, gsap, scrollmagic

I am fairly new to front end dev with JavaScript, and found several videos, code, documentations on using GSAP with ScrollMagic, but all the syntax are outdated and not functional. I just want to know the basics.

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
var tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.staggerFrom(".box", 1.25, {
  scale: 0,
  cycle: {
    y: [-50, 50]
  },
  ease: Elastic.easeOut,
  stagger: {
    from: "center",
    amount: 0.25
  }
});

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#stage",
  triggerHook: 0
})
  .addIndicators({
    colorTrigger: "white",
    colorStart: "white",
    colorEnd: "white",
    indent: 5
  })
  .setTween(tl)
  .addTo(controller);
```

Comment: What is your question? Btw, GSAP has released its own scroll-based plugin which is ScrollTrigger, use this and you would have better docs.

Comment: @phucbm the command lines from scroll trigger's documentations is not running. Maybe the issue can be that I am not using the correct script tags in my html.. can you verify on your device and send me those snippets?